# Generate/Encrypt unique keys based on a string (like Windows Azure storage keys)

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I would like to generate an unique key something like Azure does for storage accounts:

[image]

This is one key example

```
XrmGWqu9qpgKX5G3lf+V5Bc0nFIGjGWiWhHTdMxkA5Mb4WjJ0rDV+3USWW/6fAWCrszrkr2+JUb1c5mxQdq4nw==
```

I changed the question based on the comments as it was not so clear.

Comment: If you want the output to be different and always unique, why not use a GUID instead?

Comment: It should be generated based on a string value which will be the same. Example username might be an email address, then I want to generate a unique key based on that email address, and be able to regenerate it.

Comment: why based on something if the output is different all the time? Either you want something deterministic in which case the output is the same with equal input, or something random in which case the input doesn't matter. Concatenate current time in milliseconds to the user name and do an md5

Comment: And I don't want Guid

Comment: Ok now I see my question is not so clear ...

Comment: I mean the output should be different when regenerated. Example: var value = "5"; var result = value + randomNumber // will give a different result each time

Comment: Azures keys do not work like that at all. The key it generates is not tied to a username at all. Traditionally a key should not be "encrypted" but what gets used as the source to encrypt something else. And your example is a hash not a encryption, I got a result of 12, please tell me the value I used and random number that was generated for it. You can't reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do something:

```
 using (RandomNumberGenerator random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
 {
     byte[] number = new byte[64];
     random.GetBytes(number);

     string val = Convert.ToBase64String(number);
 }
```

The result is something like this:

```
ZdhaqQoNscMrfLFy0U6tLuyPXvIrM0mn0F+dLbqcImUknJOFCPLZAcFw+paEYs0jMnyC6mee75j6IpCNAQyUfw==
```